# How can I log the requests and responses from integrated services using logbook?

Tags: java, spring, microservices, httpclient, logbook

My service sends requests for another service that in some use cases, send requests for a third service. I want to log the requests and responses generated in the interaction of my second and third services with the same correlationId that exists in the logs from my first service.
Can I do that using Logbook and java.net.http.HttpClient? And how?
regards.

I already configurated logbook at my service and I can log all requests and responses from this service correctly.
But when I call an endpoint that have interactions with another services, I can't configure the correlation and log the requests and responses as I want.